# Add custom steps in Azure Deployment Slots during swap

Tags: azure, asp.net, azure-web-apps

I'm analysing the Azure Deployment Slots functionality of Azure App Service to adopt zero downtime deployment strategy and i'm curious if it's possible to define some custom steps to be performed during automatic swap operation. I need to execute series of powershell scripts. I could've run them in my Azure DevOps deployment pipeline after ensuring that swap was successfull, but in this case i will loose benefit of swap back in case of any unpredictible failure and will need to execute that scripts manually.

My question is - is there any way to customize swap operation by adding some steps by myself?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't undertake additional steps in the swap operation, it's purely there to swap the slot over and that is it.
Any sort of orchestration you need to do around this should be done in your deployment pipeline prior to, or after, the swap.

You can run some tests as part of your pipeline and swap back using the pipeline if you want.